# STM32f103 ADC 1 strange behavior

Tags: stm32, adc, keil

I'm currently working on a project which uses the STM32f103c8 blue pill to read analog signals from a 3 current sense amplifiers.

I noticed that the values were correct most of the time but would randomly jump to zero or close-to-zero values even when the analog signal was verifiably constant.

At first I figured it was because of noise or something related to my PCB design so I removed the blue pill and placed it in a bread board and ran its own 3.3v supply straight to the 3 analog inputs B1 B0 and A7.

I saw through my kiel debugger that I was getting the values 4095 but they would still randomly jump to 0 or some very low number like 4 and 16 for example.

I also replaced the blue pill to ensure that the only other variable is my code. There has to be something I'm doing wrong when initializing.

The code below is a snitbit of what I've got for the ADC initialization.

```
void ADCInit () {
  RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_ADCPRE_DIV6; //sets ADC clock freguency to 12mhz accoring to datasheet
  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_ADC1EN | RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;  //enable ADC and alt fuction pins
  RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN; //enable DMA

  ADC1->SMPR2 |= ADC_SMPR2_SMP7_0 | ADC_SMPR2_SMP7_1 | ADC_SMPR2_SMP7_2; // setting sample rates to max
  ADC1->SMPR2 |= ADC_SMPR2_SMP8_0 | ADC_SMPR2_SMP8_1 | ADC_SMPR2_SMP8_2; // setting sample rates to max
  ADC1->SMPR2 |= ADC_SMPR2_SMP9_0 | ADC_SMPR2_SMP9_1 | ADC_SMPR2_SMP9_2; // setting sample rates to max
  ADC1->SQR1 |= 3 << 20; //turning sequence mode on 
  ADC1->SQR3 |= 9 << 0; // setting channel 9 as the first in sequence
  ADC1->SQR3 |= 8 << 5; // setting channel 8 as the second in sequence 
  ADC1->SQR3 |= 7 << 10; // setting channel 7 as the third in sequence
  ADC1->CR1 |= ADC_CR1_SCAN; // setting ADC to scan mode
  ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_DMA;  // turning on DMA for ADC

  DMA1_Channel1 ->CPAR = (uint32_t)(&(ADC1->DR)); // passing data register of ADC to DMA
  DMA1_Channel1 ->CMAR = (uint32_t)currentSen; // passing array to DMA
  DMA1_Channel1 ->CNDTR = 3; // set DMA to count 3 times
  DMA1_Channel1 ->CCR |= DMA_CCR1_CIRC | DMA_CCR1_MINC | DMA_CCR1_MSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR1_PSIZE_0; // DMA settings
  DMA1_Channel1 ->CCR |= DMA_CCR1_EN; // enable DMA
    
  ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_CONT; // turn on ADC continuous mode 
  ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_ADON; // turn on ADC
  ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_CAL; //Enable calibration

  while ((ADC1->CR2 >> 2) & 0x1UL); //Wait until calibration completed

  ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_ADON; //Set CR2_ADON again to turn on ADC and start converting

  for (int y = 0; y < 1000000; y++){}
}
```

This is the function that is called to initialize the ADC; below is the code that sets the GPIOs:

```
void GPIOInit() {
  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPBEN;
  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
  // enable port a clock
  GPIOA->CRL = 0xc8bbbbbb; //sets all portA to alt push pull except A6 for MISO and set A7 to input pull down pull up for ADC
  GPIOB->CRL = 0x444844CC; //set B1 and B0 to input pull down pull up
}
```

I'm hoping that is easy enough to read and hopefully someone can help me figure out what exactly is causing this weird behavior.

Comment: I see you ORing a bunch of bits into registers, but nothing to guarantee they were clear in the first place...

Comment: what do you mean? I have checked through the debugger that the registers were set. anything to help clarify